# How to upload HTML to GitHub

Tags: html, css, github, slack

I've been working on my senior project. My team made me do font end in bootstrap which I've done. They now want me to upload to bootstrap. Too embarrassed to say IDK. what do I do . one guy said i can send it over slack or upload to GitHub. Please, how do i upload to GitHub or send over slack my html and CSS.

Comment: If you've created markup and styling with (HTML & CSS), can't you just zip the files together and send them to your classmates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your HTML & CSS files to a GitHub repository, rather than having to use Git to push your files to GitHub, as Chris said.

All you need to do is:

1. Make a [new, empty GitHub repository](https://github.com/new) and fill out some information about your repository (make sure you are logged in to GitHub or made a GitHub account already!)
2. Once you have created the repository, click "uploading an existing file"
3. Drag & drop your HTML & CSS files or choose your HTML/CSS files manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy and paste the HTML & CSS code in your text editor to slack, this is the easiest option in your current situation. When they are talking about GitHub, they are asking you to push the code to a repository. In order to do this, you will need a GitHub account, create the said repository.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_Clau1bYco

I really recommend the above link as it will take you step by step through git and github, once you are set up with this, your team will be able to "pull" the code from yourself through github. This is far easier as they do not have to set up the folders to paste code into.

I hope this gives you a clear idea,

Kind Regards